# Is there any homeless hospice run by Archdiocese of Toronto?

Tags: redemption

I might get homeless.

Is there any holy sacred good clean Christ-like homeless hospice run by Archdiocese of Toronto? Cardinal Collin's administration.

Comment: Have you approached the Chancery Office in Toronto?

Comment: No. I haven't. But as you mentioned I will. Thank you.

Comment: Or talk to your parish priest. They probably know ones near you.